# Grid System and Inline-Block spacing

Tags: html, grid, css, spacing

i've just seen http://csswizardry.com/2013/02/introducing-csswizardry-grids/ and the demo to it (http://csswizardry.com/csswizardry-grids/). I think this is a pretty good approach to solve grids in CSS. So i checked out the source code to see, how it's done and i saw one little thing, which i can't really figure out how it was done.

This Grid System is not using floats but inline-block elements, which is a good thing. But every time i am using inline blocks for percentage width columns / grids etc. i have this inline block spacing. I know there are several ways (mostly just changes in your HTML) to get rid of this spacing: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

But in the grid system i showed you there is none of those fixes (as far as i can see) and still there is no inline-block spacing at all if you check the source code. Just to show you the problem i mostly have here is a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nN8mV/

HTML

```
<p>Floating columns (width 33.3%)</p>
<div class="grid cf">
    <div class="grid__item">Test</div>
    <div class="grid__item">Test</div>
    <div class="grid__item">Test</div>
</div>
<p>Inline Block columns (width 33.3%)</p>
<div class="grid grid--inlineblock">
    <div class="grid__item">Test</div>
    <div class="grid__item">Test</div>
    <div class="grid__item">Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
    .grid__item {
        float: left;
        width: 33.3%;  
        background: red;
    }
    .grid--inlineblock .grid__item {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

You probably know that, but the 33.3% width doesn't work, because of this spacing. The grid systems doesn't seem to have this problem, although it is using "display: inline-block" as well. So my question: How did CSS Wizardy solve this problem? I can't figure it out and changing the HTML (see CSS Tricks link above) doesn't really work very often, because of CMS generated content or other stuff, where you cant adapt your HTML.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demo from Csswizardry you linked uses comment html hack:

```
<div class="grid__item"></div><!--
--><div class="grid__item"></div>
```

Check their demo source.

Also updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nN8mV/1/)

Comment: Oh my bad, totally overseen the comments inside the source. I was too focused on the CSS instead :) Thanks, that answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your HTML, you'll have to give  the container `font-size: 0` and reset the `font-size` in the columns or give the columns negative margins (can be troublesome).

> More details:
>   http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: You are right, but this method has a lot of disadvantages (Safari 5 + Search engines + Old Android). As far as i red, there is no good CSS-fix yet, so we'll have to stick to HTML comments for now...

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just pointing out the css "hacks" because the poster cited he couldn't change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
.grid--inlineblock {
   word-spacing: -4px;
}
```

And on the child item reset the word-spacing

```
.grid--inlineblock .grid__item {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    word-spacing: normal;
}
```

You can checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nN8mV/3/) fiddle.

I'm unsure if this is the best technique but it seems to work rather well.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it always depends on the font you are using. As far as i know there is no reliable CSS hack yet. You need to remove the whitespace in your HTML for now. But that works out pretty well.

Comment: Ahh yeah my bad but I guess it's a work around until someone finds something better if you don't like using the comments.

Comment: Somebody needs to come up with a solution before Flexbox has a decent support. After that we probably won't need inline-block / floats for grid systems :)

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox solves this problem nowadays.

You could do the following instead:

```
.grid--inlineblock .grid__item {
        display: flex;
}
```

And that should resolve the spacing issues.